# Streams stopped working on Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundcloud

My app, among other things, streams clips of songs through SoundCloud. It's been working great for the past few weeks, but last night, in my MediaPlayer's prepare() method, it started getting error (1, -1004), which is ridiculously weird because I can still play the streams that I get in my desktop browser. Has something recently changed on SoundCloud that could have broken this?

This is a snippet of my code that I used to confirm that this was a problem:

```
    String url = replacementUrlEdit.getText().toString();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        showInfoPopup("exception preparing: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Pretty standard stuff. The url that I end up passing to the MediaPlayer is the redirected stream url, in a format like https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/XXXXXXXXXX.128.mp3?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Expires=1406322087&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D

The error I get is this:

```
07-25 16:56:29.801    4425-4696/com.example E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
07-25 16:56:29.861    4425-4425/com.example E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1004)
```

I have also tried it preparing synchronously, in which case I get an IOException with error 0x1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Experienced the same under ios